# Unable to post a large XML in querystring using REST API

Tags: c#, api

I have a rest api where I need to post a large xml using post method.

The controller where I post the data needs value under inboundRequest parameter.

The code works fine when I call the url as follows for small data
eg: http://localhost/api/GetXMl?inboundRequest="data" but does not work when large XML is posted:

Update Code:

```
 byte[] bytes;

    bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input.value);
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/api/GETXMl?inboundRequest=" + input.value);

    string postData =  input.value;

    request.ContentType = "text/xml; encoding='utf-8'";
    request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.Timeout = 1000000000;
    request.ReadWriteTimeout = 100000000;
    Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
    requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    requestStream.Close();
    HttpWebResponse response;
    response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        string responseStr = new StreamReader(responseStream).ReadToEnd();
        return responseStr;
    }
    return null;
```

And getting error ->
{"Unable to read data from the transport connection: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine."}

Comment: Why are you using query string fields for a POST? The idea is that you submit data to the server in the request body when you POST.

Comment: @spender: I agree, but the xml which I send should be inside the value inboundRequest. How to send the value in that case with the parameter

Comment: @psobhan Are you sure that "GetXml?inboundRequest=" + SoapInput.inboundRequest is valid uri? Do you actually need PostAsJsonAsync ?

Comment: @spender: I am very new to rest api's. The URL is valid and currently I have updated the code (check above) and getting new errors. Correct me if my approach is wrong

Answer (score 0):

You can apply different solutions depending your scenario. Is this a webform application, webapi or mvc?.
You can use JSON data to post if you are using JSON media formatter. For example:
{"inboundRequest":"my xml data"}. Your json data will be automatically mapped to the parameter named inboundRequest.

Or you can post application/x-www-form-urlencoded as you would post the xml data from a textbox named inboundRequest like 
inboundRequest="xml text". Again the form member (inboundRequest) value will be mapped to your inboundRequest parameter.

Similar if you use XML media formatter just post